# composer update authentication on packagist

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5, packagist

I have a problem with the composer update for my project made in laravel 5.
Everytime I want to update the composer with other packages (from Packagist) I get an authentication box (not suposed to be one) and then even if I input my github/packagist account or not I end like this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Authentication required (packagist.org):
      Username:
      Password:



  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Invalid credentials for 'http://packagist.org/p/doctrine/inflector$caf0d38e
  3001eb2cbabe4192f701affcc10254307a3c01fa6b41a5579b2b648e.json', aborting.
```

I tried until now, to install composer after deleting vendor's folder and composer lock, but again the auth is appearing. 
I made another laravel project but I start with lot's of vendor folder (like doctrine inflector), and they need auth.
I also tried a github token, on composer json.

Anyone knows what is the problem?
Thank you in advance.

```
D:\Code\pricer>composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: FAIL
The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
 Disabling it when using Composer is recommended.
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

I don't have problems with the rate limit for an auth and platform settings fail because of xdebug.

And when I am deleting that package and installing composer again

```
  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.14 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.0 -> no matching
package found.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.14 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.0 -> no matching
package found.
```

Composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.6.*@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your `composer.json`? Have you tried without `doctrine/inflector` package? What's the output if so?

Comment: I wrote all those informations in the main post:d

Comment: Thanks. I'd try installing packages step by step (to new directory) and observe what fail and when. Just tried myself and was successful.

Via console: `composer require "laravel/framework:5.0.*"`, 
`composer require "illuminate/html:5.0.*@dev"`,
`composer require "doctrine/dbal:2.6.*@dev"`

Comment: I've tried your way buy nothing good happened. Then I removed homestead/vagrant/composer/php 5.4(wamp) and reinstalled them all with a php version 5.5.12, and now I can't even to use the composer commands

[ErrorException]
fopen(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: Thank you, I'll try myself the rest, I think my computer has a problem and if it's fixed then everything will gonna be alright:d

Comment: I solved the part with the fopen(), but now it prompts me again for auth.

[link to error with composer -vvv](http://pastebin.com/z5V1df3X)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with authentication, so I ran this code:

```
composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Then I ran the update again and it worked!

Try it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment You saved my life

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a port problem. It is unable to connect to a specific port because of blocking of ports on your system by your admin. Which is the reason why it is asking for this authentication.

Try connecting to a home network or mobile network and do the composer update. It should go smooth without asking for credentials.

Do mark it as answer if this worked for you.